# Extracting numbers from String

Tags: r

Basic question...
I've a string and I'm trying to extract the numbers from a string using the below.

```
str2="<P>3.1 Design objectives ..... 
<Link>25 
</Link> </P>"
str2
a<-strapply(str2,"\\d+",as.numeric,simplify=TRUE)
a
```

This returns `3`, `1`, and `25` which is fine. (It's ok that `3.1` is split up)

However, if the string has no numbers at all:

```
pr <- "This is a test string"
b<-strapply(pr,"\\d+",as.numeric,simplify=TRUE)
```

`b`  returns:

```
[[1]]
NULL
```

How can I use the above to detect the presence of a number(s) in a string?

`is.null(b)` returned `False` as it should.

`length(b)` gave `1`, which is the `NULL` Object?

So, is it right to say that the string does not contain any numbers if `length(b)` is `1`? Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I think strapply is from the gsubfn package.  Just wanted to add that because I was not familiar with it.

Comment: Yes, its from the gsubfn package and the library has been loaded. Sorry, didnt post that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would `unlist` the result and test its `length`, For example using `strapplyc`:

```
  (ll <- as.numeric(unlist(strapplyc(str2,"\\d+",simplify = TRUE))))
   numeric(0)
   length(ll)
   [1] 0
```

**EDIT** Rereading your question, I think it is better/safer to convert your XML structure to a simple text before appyling regular expression on it. For example you can do this :

```
library(XML)
toString(xmlToList(str2))
[1] "3.1 Design objectives ..... \n, 25,  \n"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
require(gsubfn)
pr <- "This is a test string"
b<-strapply(pr,"\\d+",as.numeric,simplify=TRUE)
if( !length(b[[1]]) ){TRUE}
#[1] TRUE
```

(This is the standard way of testing whether a list element is NULL.)